# Visual Studio feature for automatically generating relevant catch-blocks for exceptions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2012

Let's say I have the following method in C#:

```
XslCompiledTransform myObject;

public void foo() {
  try {
    myObject.Transform(input, output);
  } catch (???) {
  }
}
```

Is there a menu option or functionality in Visual Studio 2012 which automatically generates all the `catch` blocks for the exceptions which might occur in `XslCompiledTransform`? Like "Generate catch blocks"?

Comment: Are you referring to a "feature" like the "Implement interface" option or to a more abstract, programing guide line of some sort?

Comment: It's more the question if VS 2012 has some menu option like "Generate catch blocks" :-)

Comment: I presumed so. I thing the tags on your question are a bit misleading. There's no reference to "Visual Studio". I agree with Tigran's answer but does not really relate to the question. I think he was also thrown off by the question/tags. Could you maybe edit your question to make it a bit clearer?

Comment: @Robert I updated my answer to add information about tools

Comment: I'm guessing this idea is from how eclipse/netbeans does it for Java? The short answer is no, and it probably never will. Methods in Java include what exceptions are thrown in the method signature, which means it's quick and easy to do in an IDE without reading the code first. 
Also, most of the time you're going to want those exceptions to be thrown and handled either later, or not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no smart way to automatically generate all catch blocks of all possible exception. But Visual Studio shows related exception list to function call as shown below.

[image: Visual Studio shown related exception]

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't think it's *generally* a good practice. IMO you should only catch exception you consider *possible* to be thrown.

This means in your example:

- you shouldn't catch `ArgumentNullException` in your example, but check that `input`/`output` are not null before calling your method
- I would catch `IOException` instead of `DirectoryNotFoundException`/`FileNotFoundException` **unless** you have a different exception handling for both cases

Remember catching specific exceptions is only interesting is you have a specific exception handling associated. If it's just "log then re-throw", then don't catch specific exceptions.

---

EDIT: I assume you are looking for a tool that does the job. I'm not aware of such a tool (you might want to check on visualstudiogallery). What's interesting though, is that [Exception Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/exception-hunter/), a tool from RedGate that was doing this job, has been discontinued for interesting reasons. Have a look:

> With the release of .NET 4.0 and WPF, the number of exceptions that
>   the CLR can throw was greatly increased, to the point of being
>   overwhelming. The exclusions list can no longer cover all the unlikely
>   exceptions that the CLR may throw. This means that, although Exception
>   Hunter will provide accurate results, these results will include a
>   long list of potential exceptions, most of which are nothing to worry
>   about. In essence, the tool has become a lot less usable and makes
>   your job harder than it should be. This goes against our ingeniously
>   simple ethos, so we have decided to stop selling new licenses for the
>   product.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not bad practise tll it fits your needs. It's hard to say if it good for you or not,as it depends on your app structure and *expected* behaviour.

Usually try to catch them on highest logical level possible, where you are flexible enough on your app to make decisione wither `throw` it or handle it in some way.